# Regular expressions to find file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My problem is i have multiple strings which combined together with different combinations can form a file name.I need to find the file which closely matches these multiple strings in any combination. Is it possible?

Example :

> String1="Black chevron gold glimmer skin for the apple iphone"
>   String2="IPhone 4s"

Actual file name to match is `"Black chevron gold glimmer skin for the apple iphone for Iphone 4s"`

Having String1 and String2 how should I proceed to find file name which closely resembles the actual file? In the above example the strings are linked with a "for" but it's not always true, it can be anything. So i need to match closest possible name using both strings.

Comment: Why regex? Why not [Strings.InStr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47d6yh63(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: How do you define “most closely resembles?”  Given that definition, how would you calculate each filename’s score?

Comment: Mariano That works!!! thanks

Comment: You can try DirectoryInfo 's EnumerateFiles() method to find files based on search pattern. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383574%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Lorehead, i'm not sure about that. What would be your approach?

Comment: I think I would suggest something like largest matching substring, or matches the most words (preferably in the same order).  But finding the web page that “best matches” a user-provided string is precisely Google’s business model.  It turns out to be a very deep and lucrative problem.

Comment: string.Contains is enough..0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by concatenating the two strings together and replace the spaces with `.+` and add `.*` before and after the sentence, we could get this greedy pattern :

```
.*(Black.+chevron.+gold.+glimmer.+skin.+for.+the.+apple.+iphone).*(Iphone.+4s).*
```

which will match this file name :

`this is Black chevron gold glimmer skin for the apple iphone for Iphone 4s.jpg`

check and try this online at : https://regex101.com/r/eA7cW9/1

- I think the concatenating\replace\match code will be easy for you, but i can provide it too if this pattern matches your case.

Comment: Thats awesome!!!! Only problem is tokenizing the string and concatinating with .+. Any easy way for this?

Comment: `var pattern = ".*(" + "str1".Replace(" ",".+") + ").*(" + "str2".Replace(" ",".+") + ").*";`
 dirty, but works!